# how do you convert epoch to readable date format in javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am building a chart using highcharts. Values on xaxis are epoch format. When I try to show the values, it comes up as epoch. How would I convert to this to readable format in javascript. This is what I have:

```
tooltip: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                this.x +': '+ this.y;

                  }
},
```

Comment: This might help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Highcharts.dateFormat`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat%28%29) function. Note you have to multiply your epoch number with 1000, as `Highcharts.dateFormat` needs a JavaScript date timestamp (milliseconds since Jan 1st 1970).

```
tooltip: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                Highcharts.dateFormat('%d.%m.%Y', this.x*1000) +': '+ this.y;

                  }
},
```

Comment: I have a quick question. Is it possible to draw linear trend line with hightcharts?

Comment: please create a new question for that